# Only echo Page Content (not page title & page content together)

Tags: functions, pages

I am working on a child theme of the WordPress Twenty Ten theme. I have several pages in WordPress (About page, Testimonials page, Contact page, etc.). I want to only echo the page content (the actual about/testimonials/contact page written content and images BUT NOT the page title). I know I can echo just the page title with:

```
<?php single_post_title(); // echos About OR Testimonials OR Contact depending on the page selected ?>
```

But I cannot find a WordPress function to echo only the page content without the page title? I tried:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
```

But it doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `the_page_content()` **outside** the loop to display only the content of the page where `the_page_content()` is supported by the following function

```
function the_page_content() {
    global $post;

    $content = '';
    if ( is_page() ) {
        $content .= apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
    }
    echo $content;
}
```

Inside the loop you can just use `the_content();`

Comment: Sorry, I had an error in my code, rectified

Answer (score 0):

```
the_content();
```

I think this is what you're looking for?

Comment: I tried this and it did not work for me.